# how to play wav file in java 1.4

Tags: java, audio, java1.4

as title
How can i play a sound file repeatedly in java v1.4?

Comment: People still use Java 1.4? And write *new* code for it? It's been EOL-ed for ages now!

Comment: @Joachim: they do. A lot of clients are installed at the "If it works, don't change, just add new modules" position. And I for sure know it.

Comment: @Tomás: that's a very irresponsible position. The security problems alone that come with such a setup can cost a lot more than any upgrade.

Comment: @Joachim: I agree. But customers pay and command.

Comment: This is ages old, but anyways. Sometimes you have to deal with obsolete systems, it just happens. In my case, is for my personal use (no customers paying or mandating anything).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to play the wav file then 'org.life.java''s answer is correct. For other format types you can use JMF( http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html ).

**Note:** JMF is obsolete now... But it will work with jdk 1.4

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class LoopSound {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL(
      "http://pscode.org/media/leftright.wav");
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.
      getAudioInputStream( url );
    clip.open(ais);
    clip.loop(0);
    javax.swing.JOptionPane.
      showMessageDialog(null, "Close to exit!");
  }
}
```

Comment: `AudioSystem.getClip()` does not exist in JDK 1.4

Answer (score 0):

This will work in JDK 1.4 (tested in Windows XP and JDK 1.4.2_06).
The other answer fails because as correctly stated in the comments, `AudioSystem.getClip()` does not exist on JDK 1.4. Below is a complete source (in the form of a main function, but it's adaptable to anything else) that uses `DataLine` and plays in a separate Thread for better overall performance as well:

```java
import java.io.File;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

public class AudioTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("C:/sound1.wav"));

    AudioFormat format = ais.getFormat();
    DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
    SourceDataLine sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);

    class PlayThread extends Thread {
      private AudioInputStream ais;
      private AudioFormat format;
      private SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;

      byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[10000];

      public PlayThread(AudioInputStream ais, SourceDataLine sourceDataLine, AudioFormat format) {
        this.ais = ais;
        this.sourceDataLine = sourceDataLine;
        this.format = format;
      }

      public void run() {
        try {
          sourceDataLine.open(this.format);
          sourceDataLine.start();

          int cnt;
          while ((cnt = this.ais.read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.length)) != -1) {
            if (cnt > 0) {
              sourceDataLine.write(tempBuffer, 0, cnt);
            }
          }

          sourceDataLine.drain();
          sourceDataLine.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      }
    }

    new PlayThread(ais, sourceDataLine, format).start();

  }
}
```

Both question and answers are really old, but I just had to make this work on a fanless mini PC that only run windows XP so... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯